# Hibernate Schema Validation Error when mapping LocalDateTime to TIMESTAMP

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I added a `LocalDateTime` column in one of the entities, and as per the Postgresql [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html), this is mapped SQL-wise to the `TIMESTAMP` type.

However, when running the Spring Boot application with Hibernate in `validate` mode, startup fails due to this:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [request_date_time] in table [prepayment]; found [timestamp (Types#TIMESTAMP)], but expecting [bytea (Types#VARBINARY)]
```

Any ideas what could cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be caused by using a version of hibernate that does not support  types like LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime and similar date classes.
In order to fix this, try adding a hibernate-java8 depedency, for example, if you are using gradle:

> compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-java8', version:
>   '5.0.12.Final'

Comment: Thanks, solved it. Did not have knowledge about this 'hibernate-java8' project, good to know.